# Pandas aggregate with dynamic column names

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a script that generates a pandas data frame with a varying number of value columns. As an example, this df might be

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
'group_color' : ['green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue'],
'val1': [5, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
'val2' : [4, 2, 8, 5, 7]
})

  group group_color  val1  val2
0     A       green     5     4
1     A       green     2     2
2     A       green     3     8
3     B        blue     4     5
4     B        blue     5     7
```

My goal is to get the grouped mean for each of the value columns. In this specific case (with 2 value columns), I can use

```
df.groupby('group').agg({"group_color": "first", "val1": "mean", "val2": "mean"})

      group_color      val1      val2
group                                
A           green  3.333333  4.666667
B            blue  4.500000  6.000000
```

but that does not work when the data frame in question has more value columns (val3, val4 etc.).
Is there a way to dynamically take the mean of "all the other columns" or "all columns containing val in their names"?

Comment: is group_color always the same for one group?

Comment: @QuangHoang: yes, that is the case, but I would still like to retain it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

More easy like

```
df.groupby('group').agg(lambda x : x.head(1) if x.dtype=='object' else x.mean())
Out[63]: 
      group_color      val1      val2
group                                
A           green  3.333333  4.666667
B            blue  4.500000  6.000000
```

Comment: nice solution! Can you explain why the dtype of the non-numeric columns is object?

Comment: @MartijnVanAttekum this is a dtype in panda, string and others all classified as object

Answer (score 9):

If your `group_color` is always the same within one group, you can do:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['group','group_color'],aggfunc='mean')
```

Output:

```
                       val1      val2
group group_color                    
A     green        3.333333  4.666667
B     blue         4.500000  6.000000
```

In the other case, you can build the dictionary and pass it to `agg`:

```
agg_dict = {f: 'first' if f=='group_color' else 'mean' for f in df.columns[1:]}
df.groupby('group').agg(agg_dict)
```

Which output:

```
      group_color      val1      val2
group                                
A           green  3.333333  4.666667
B            blue  4.500000  6.000000
```

Comment: You're `pivot_table` answer is the way to go.  I used almost the same thing but added a `reset_index`.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you will have to apply both aggregation functions separately (that or repeat `"valn": "mean"` as many times as `valx` columns). `Groupby.agg` can take a dictionary but the keys must be individual columns.

The way I'd do this is using `DataFrame.filter` to select the subset of the dataframe with the columns following the format of `valx`, aggregate with the mean, and then assign new columns with the aggregated results on the other columns:

```
(df.filter(regex=r'^val').groupby(df.group).mean()
   .assign(color = df.group_color.groupby(df.group).first()))

         val1      val2    color
group                           
A      3.333333  4.666667  green
B      4.500000  6.000000   blue
```

Answer (score 4):

Per OP's comment

[image]

We can group by both `'group'` and `'group_color'` without the risk of there being more than one unique `'group_color'` per `'group'`

Consequently:

```
df.groupby(['group', 'group_color']).mean().reset_index(level=1)

      group_color      val1      val2
group                                
A           green  3.333333  4.666667
B            blue  4.500000  6.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with 2 dictionaries that you can combine like this:

```
df.groupby('group').agg({**{'group_color': 'first'}, **{c: 'mean' for c in df.columns if c.startswith('val')}})
```

In this case you have one `dict` with fixed aggregations and other with dynamic column selection.